# How to add a search results Yammer widget?

Tags: yammer

I want to be able to display search results in yammer network in a widget on my web-app. I am able to get search results by making a call to the search API. However, I cannot find any way to convert it into a feed so that it can be displayed as a widget using Yammer Embed.

I have read the docs thoroughly but am unable to find a way to do so. Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Embed widget doesn't provide a search view at this time. You can configure it for different feed types, but not a search term. In order to create a client-side search results widget you'd need to use the Yammer [JS SDK](https://developer.yammer.com/yammer-sdks/#javascript-sdk) and make calls to the [search](https://developer.yammer.com/restapi/#rest-search) end point. You'd be responsible for formatting the results, but you'd have more control than you would with Embed.